# Firebase Realtime Database with Arduino no longer supported?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino, esp8266

I made an Arduino sketch that uses the Firebase realtime database (with ESP8266). Last week I received a warning: "Your cloud firebase database refuses requests from clients and continues to do so until you update your security rules" I looked into these rules and couldn't find anything for Arduino to apply these rules.

Since then I got: `Exception (9)` when this line is called:

```
if(Firebase.getString("Barcodes/"+String(i)+"/ID").equals(barcode)){
```

It just worked beforehand.

Does Firebase no longer support the Arduino environment for their databases?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The warning isn't at all specific to your Arduino environment.  It's telling you that the data in your database is not secure, because you don't have good security rules set up.

The problem with environments like Arudino is that they don't directly support Firebase Authentication, which is required to make good security rules that limit per-user access.  If you want to allow your device direct access to your database, it necessarily has to allow universal read and write access.  This has always been the case.  The only thing that changed is that Firebase is now alerting you to the fact that anyone can read and write your data.